Measure, Integration and Real analysis: Vitali covering lemma
The following are the definition and lemma according to the book Measure, Integration and Real analysis on page 103:
Def 4.2: Suppose I is a bounded nonempty open interval of R. Then 3*I denotes the open interval with the same center as I and three times the length of I.
Lemma 4.4(Vitali Covering Lemma): Suppose $I_{1}, I_{2},..., I_{n}$ is a list of bounded nonempty open intervals of R. Then, there exists a disjoint sublist $I_{k1}, I_{k2}, ..., I_{km}$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} I_{I} \subset \bigcup\limits_{ki=1}^{km} (3*I_{ki})$.
But then, considering two open intervals which are (0,1) and (1.9,2.1). We have 3*(0,1) = (-1,2) and 3*(1.9,2.1)=(1.7,2.3). We see that (-1,2) doesn't contain (1.9,2.1) and (1.7,2.3) doesn't contain (-1,2). Moreover, (1.7,2.3) and (-1,2) are not disjoint. I'm confused where my mistake is.

In this example, the two intervals you began with are already disjoint, so the output of the lemma is the same two intervals.
It’s not the intervals $3I_{k_j}$ which need to be pairwise disjoint, but the intervals $I_{k_j}$ in the sub-collection.
